# How do I determine the impedance of Z in this circuit?

Tags: passive-networks

I have a circuit shown as follows:

[image]

Known values:

V1: 5 VRMS, F = 4kHz.

V2: 0.5 VRMS @ -28.8 degrees.

Impedance Z = r + L + C.

How can Z be determined?

---

I've attempted to solve this quickly, does this look mathematically sound?

[image]

Comment: microSiemens or microseconds?? :) please consider the correct use of capitals

Comment: Do you know how to find the impedance of a capacitor or an inductor alone?

Comment: It's microseconds. Phase shift in degrees is given by (360)(frequency)(delta t).

Yes, XL = j(omega)L, XC = -j/(omega)(C). However, the value of C, L, r & R are not given.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because homework needs an attempt at a solution

Answer (score 1):

Using the voltage divider rule,

$$\frac{V_2}{V_1} = \frac{R }{R + Z}$$

With measurement only at one frequency, you won't be able to determine \$r\$, \$L\$, or \$C\$, but if the goal is only to find \$Z\$, that doesn't matter.

Comment: The nature of the impedance is just asking if the imaginary part is positive or negative.

Comment: You can get the complex value of Z by simple algebra from the formula I provided and the well-known rules for arithmetic with complex numbers.